# Eyecon jQuery Color Picker Onchange background change

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I'm using the color picker by eyecon http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

What I want to do is simple (that's what I think), I want to change the Body background instantly as soon as I drop down the color picker palette using jQuery here's a sample what I'm looking for but except I want to add the colorselector box instead of clicking on the text and the box appears I really don't like that I want the colorselector box, as soon as it drop downs the color palette I want to see a live preview of the color changing here's and example of what I want to do but instead of clicking on the text it shows the colorselector box.

Demo http://jsbin.com/ozibiq/

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit more? As i understand it, you want the color automatically selected (defined in `color` on the js call) to apply to the background as you drop down the color picker?

Comment: here's another demo of what i need help on http://jsfiddle.net/JWjEK/3/embedded/result/

Comment: That doesn't make it any easier to understand, can you separate both color pickers and set aside the one you're having problems with?

Comment: here's the sample by itself http://jsfiddle.net/JWjEK/4/embedded/result/

Comment: Ok, now that we have the sample isolated, you want to have the pre-selected color applied as you open up the color picker, correct?